# Module Creation: post process problems

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Goodmorning everyone,

I'm developing a module for prestashop 1.7, at the moment I'm having problems intercepting the postprocess method in the main class of my module.

I need to do the checks on submit the form (which are on the user profile page, where I set personal information).

From what I understand, in a form a submit is made, the first thing that is called in a class is precisely the postProcess () method that takes care of validating the data received from the form just submissive (correct me if I'm wrong).

The problem is that when I submit my form it does not enter the postPorcess () method (I checked for a die ("test") and it does not even show the latter), while if I do the check I need by invoking my method staff inside a hook is made,

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel,

This might be an endpoint problem, however, if you are sure to just handle the request via this Class, just use Tools::getValue('something_in_form') / Tools::isSubmit('var') to check that it's sent.

You don't really need to apply this one. If you need example, you should check Prestashop's native modules or Admin controllers, as it depends a lot of where you need to do this.

My thought after some years of module dev is that you should use a module front controller endpoint as you would with an API and a do a response in JSON like this example :

```
<?php

class DummyModuleNameAjaxModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
  public function initContent()
  {
    $response = array();

    require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'dummymodulename/dummymodulename.php';

    $mod = new dummymodulename;

    if (Tools::isSubmit('action') && Tools::isSubmit('var') && Tools::getValue('var') == $mod->getSomethingForSecurity()) {

        $context = Context::getContext();

        $cart = $context->cart;

        switch (Tools::getValue('action')) {

            case 'dummy_action_name':

                // Don't forget to type it with an INT or secure this entry with strip_tags
                $my_var = Tools::getValue('var');

                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    echo Tools::jsonEncode($response);

    die;
  }
}
```

Comment: so it is not necessary to use the postProcess () method to validate the data sent by the form? at this point I could ulitize my personal method and recall it from the hook

Comment: You totally should do that